# Identify a Azure Relay ServiceBus Listener

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I am experimenting with Windows Azure Relay Service Bus and WCF... I have a Service Bus with 3 listeners, is there a way to find out any information about where those three listeners point to?

As I started only one WCF service, it's a bit weird I'm seeing 3 listeners so I'd like to find out what's what...

Thank you!